# how would you compute a sample of 30 observations in this scenario?

Tags: r

let   [image]

T1=2log(x̅)-1

T2=log(min(X1...Xn)*max(X1..Xn))

I want to compute T1 and T2  for n=30. I am thinking of using a for loop for T1 but I am pretty sure there is an easier way for it.
  here is my attempt I don't really know how to go about T2 to be honest.

```
#calculating T1
    sum=0
    for (i in 1:30)
    {
     b=x*i
    sum=sum+b
    }
    sum
    T1=2*log(1/30*b)-1
    T1
```

Comment: Can I suggest that if you show us the code for your *slow* approach, others may find it easier to suggest a fast approach for getting the same result?

Answer (score 0):

What about map function?

map_dbl()

Can work better

Comment: do you mean for T1 or for T2

Answer (score 0):

I you want more efficient approaches, maybe you can try the code below for `T1` and `T2`

```
T1 <- 2*log(mean(X))-1
T2 <- log(prod(range(X)))
```

or

```
T2 <- sum(log(range(X)))
```